# Ant for script how to continue if any iteration fails

Tags: ant

I writing an ant build file to check all translate files in a directory.
I want the ant for script to continue checking the rest files if an checking error in any file appear.
My ant task:

```
    <taskdef name="validate" classname="ValidateTranslateFile">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${ant-libs-dir}/TranslateFileUtilities.jar" />
            <pathelement location="../web/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.5.jar" />
            <pathelement location="../web/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang3-3.5.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <for param="program">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="../web/WEB-INF" includes="*.txt" />
        </path>
        <sequential>
            <validate targetFile="@{program}" checkLanguages="true" checkKeysOrder="true" />
        </sequential>
    </for>

</target>
```

the Result:
it checks the files till the first error appear, and then the BUILD FAILED.

Could any one help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for task is not part of standard ANT. It is a 3rd party extension documented here:

http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html

The documentation suggests using a "keepgoing" attribute to ignore errors, this might be the answer you're looking for.

If this is a custom ANT task you are writing, perhaps you should consider [refactoring the code to operate on a fileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-tasks-filesets-properties.html#filesets)? This would enable you to call task as follows:

```
<validate checkLanguages="true" checkKeysOrder="true">
  <fileset dir="../web/WEB-INF" includes="*.txt" />
</validate>
```

Simpler and more robust.

Comment: thanks for the solution. actually I read the code in that page before, but I couldn't understand the Methodology of this refactoring.
do you know how to iterate on the founded files?

Comment: @AhmadAl-Khazraji I did some searching here's some examples extracted from open source projects: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileSet. Personally I prefer to extend Ant using groovy scripts, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075017/ant-process-the-files-in-the-subfolder-using-tasks/5083342#5083342